# Creating a total row to display the total difference of column items in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a total row that takes items from a column and displays the difference in the total field as opposed to the sum. Is this even possible in SQL?

```
SELECT P.Part_Number, P.Units_On_Hand 
FROM Part AS P 
WHERE P.Part_Number IN ('AX12', 'AZ52')
```

This is the query I currently have to display the items I need the processing to be done on. How can I amend it to incorporate a total column to show the difference?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: It would be in a table with 2 columns, the first being a description column ('P.Part_Number'), the second with a quantity value ('P.Units_On_Hand'). There would naturally then be be two rows holding these two records, and a final row to display the total difference between the two.

Comment: Example which displays structure with actual data would be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(
    select part_number, SUM(units_on_hand) total
    from yourtable
    where part_number IN ('AX12', 'AZ52')
    group by part_number
)
    select t1.part_number, t2.part_number, abs(t1.total-t2.total)
    from cte t1
        inner join cte t2
        on t1.part_number<t2.part_number
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer podiluska. It works. Also, thank you for introducing me to CTE.